# Testing python function all types

Tags: python, function, testing, pytest

Hi everyone I'm beginner in python and I want to test my function. But I got errors.

And can I use true or false statement here too.

```
def create(name1, name2, ext='.jpg'):
    if name2:
        return '%s.%s%s' % (name1, name2, ext)
    else:
        return '%s%s' % (name1, ext)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('input, expected_result',
                         [('ff0c5.ddmn6.jpg', 'ff0c5.ddmn6.jpg'),
                          ('ff0c5.ddmn6', 'ff0c5.ddmn6.jpg'),
                          ('ff0c5.jpg', 'ff0c5.jpg')]
                         )
def test_create(input, expected_result):
    assert create(input)  is expected_result
```

And I get this error.So I need to them all pass.

```
def test_create(input, expected_result):
>       assert create(input)  is expected_result
E       TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name2'
```

Comment: the error is clear: the `create` function has two required arguments (`name1`, `name2`) but you only provide one. You need to provide an argument for `name2`, or change it to a keyword argument

Comment: But how can I mention that part use name2 or don't use? @Dan

Comment: how do you call `create` with an input of `ff0c5.ddmn6.jpg`? your function doesn't seem to handle this correctly, as the `.jpg` extension will get added twice

Comment: I change it, but in my pytest.marked.parametrize I need to give two arguments? @Dan

Comment: I think  here I have so many wrongs.

Comment: if your test is matching your `create` function, you should provide these arguments to `pytest.mark.parametrize`: `"name1, name2, expected_result"`

Comment: I think I did it, but I get --parametrize the numbers of names(3): [name1,name2, exp_res] must be equal to the number of values(2): @Dan

Answer (score 0):

In your example `name2` argument must always be passed into the function. Your test is failing because you are only passing one of two arguments into your function.

To test both logic flows you would have to pass an variable for `name2` that equates to `True` (the first test below) and `False` (the bottom three tests), this really depends on how you expect your function to be used in your application

```py
def create(name1, name2, ext=".jpg"):
    if name2:
        return "%s.%s%s" % (name1, name2, ext)
    else:
        return "%s%s" % (name1, ext)


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "name1, name2, expected_result",
    [
        ("ff0c5", "ddmn6", "ff0c5.ddmn6.jpg"),
        ("ff0c5", None, "ff0c5.jpg"),
        ("ff0c5", False, "ff0c5.jpg"),
        ("ff0c5", 0, "ff0c5.jpg"),
    ],
)
def test_create(name1, name2, expected_result):
    assert create(name1, name2) == expected_result
```

I don't know what you mean by:

> And can I use true or false statement here too.

Hope this has helped!